# Promise implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, promise

Recently I made an basic port of the JavaScript `Promise` construct to Python. Here's the basic code:

```
class Promise:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.value = None
        self.errors = []
        self._state = "unfullfilled"

        def resolve(val): 
            if self._state == "settled":
                return
            self.value = val
            self._state = "settled"
        def reject(err):
            if self._state == "settled":
               return
            self.errors.append(err)
            self._state = "settled"
        fn(resolve, reject)

    def catch(self, fn):
        if self.errors:
            for i in self.errors:
                fn(i)
                self.errors.remove(i)
        return self

    def then(self, fn):
        if not self.errors:
            fn(self.value)
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def resolve(val):
        def g(resolve, reject):
            resolve(val)
        return Promise(g)

    @staticmethod
    def reject(val):
        def g(resolve, reject):
            reject(val)
        return Promise(g)
```

What could I improve in this code?
Besides that, are there any bugs in this code?

Comment: Welcome to codereview. Have you checked [promise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/promise) module?

Comment: This code is for personal use. I was just checking if it is okay to write code in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for showing your code. You really should show us how to use it, by including unit tests, a reference URL, or with comments. At a minimum the class needs a docstring.

```
self._state = "unfullfilled"
```

Typo. Consider using `enum.Enum` instead of `str`.

```
self.value = None
```

This appears to be just wrong. (Hard to tell, since no docstring describes what valid callers may do.) A fn could choose to return `None`, yes? The usual approach for such a sentinel is to invoke `object()` to create a private object, essentially an allocated memory location that other code doesn't know about. Then test equality against *that*. If, on the other hand, you want your API to prohibit passing `None`, then you'll want to add some checks for that.

```
self.errors.remove(i)
```

That's an odd way to phrase it. The usual idiom for the loop you wrote would be to `.pop()` the initial element. Consider switching from list to deque if lots of errors might accumulate.